# Android POST data and COOKIES

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I have a username as password which I need to send to a website as part of an android application (yes it is https), and once submitted to the seerver via POST, the server should return cookies. I need to be able to capture these cookies, and allow them to be accessed in a webview which I have settup.

How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [setCookie function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) on the CookieManager instance, which you can get by calling a static method on it named getInstance.

Comment: How would I go about retrieving the response from the server?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question: actually, the easiest thing is probably to make the webview submit the form itself. Create a webview, then enable javascript in it. Then load HTML code with a form tag with the proper fields (already filled out) pointing to the proper url. Then rig a javascript onload handler to submit the form. The webview can automatically handle the storage of cookies.

Comment: That seems simple enough, but I need it to be fully automated, and the user unaware of the process. Is there a way to do this in the backhground

Comment: Just make the WebView hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in Java HttpURLConnection you can set / get a cookie this way (here is the whole connection process):

```
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();             

            //set cookie. sCookie is my static cookie string
            if(sCookie!=null && sCookie.length()>0){
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookie);                  
            }

            // Send data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream(); 
            os.write(mData.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close(); 

            // Get the response!
            int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();         
            if (httpResponseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
               throw new Exception("HTTP response code: "+httpResponseCode); 
            }

            // Get the data and pass them to the XML parser
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();                
            Xml.parse(inputStream, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, mSaxHandler);                
            inputStream.close();

            //Get the cookie
            String cookie = conn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
            if(cookie!=null && cookie.length()>0){
                sCookie = cookie;              
            }

            /*   many cookies handling:                  
            String responseHeaderName = null;
            for (int i=1; (responseHeaderName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i))!=null; i++) {
                if (responseHeaderName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
                String cookie = conn.getHeaderField(i);   
                }
            }*/                

            conn.disconnect();
```